# Bind Json data with Jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

My json data from Server

```
[
    {
        "INVESTORREF": null,
        "PROCFLAG": "Processed",
        "LOCKINBALANCE": 0,
        "ISIN": "BD0401ALHAJ8",
        "STATUS": "Pending",
        "RECORDDATE": "\/Date(1417284000000)\/",
        "EXCEPTIONDETAILS": null,
        "ISEXCEPTION": null,
        "ISCREDIT": "Y",
        "SEQUENCENO": null,
        "PREMIUM": null,
        "FREEZEBALANCE": 0,
        "CAID": "345d457a-a500-43e9-b935-faf889cbf14e",
        "IMPORTDATE": "\/Date(1427000124666)\/",
        "LASTUPDATED": "\/Date(1427000124666)\/",
        "CATYPE": "BONUS",
        "EFFECTIVEDATE": "\/Date(1326132000000)\/",
        "BOID": "1205150002440950",
        "FREEBALANCE": 5020,
        "INSTRUMENTNAME": "Business Object Solutions",
        "DRCRFLAG": "CREDIT"
    }
]
```

I want to bind this data with in a Jquery datatable

```
$('#myTable').dataTable();
```

How can i bind this json data with datatable?Need help.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Does this data change over time?

Answer (score 0):

This will help:

```
var jsonDataFromServer = [
    {
        "INVESTORREF": null,
        "PROCFLAG": "Processed",
        "LOCKINBALANCE": 0,
        "ISIN": "BD0401ALHAJ8",
        "STATUS": "Pending",
        "RECORDDATE": "\/Date(1417284000000)\/",
        "EXCEPTIONDETAILS": null,
        "ISEXCEPTION": null,
        "ISCREDIT": "Y",
        "SEQUENCENO": null,
        "PREMIUM": null,
        "FREEZEBALANCE": 0,
        "CAID": "345d457a-a500-43e9-b935-faf889cbf14e",
        "IMPORTDATE": "\/Date(1427000124666)\/",
        "LASTUPDATED": "\/Date(1427000124666)\/",
        "CATYPE": "BONUS",
        "EFFECTIVEDATE": "\/Date(1326132000000)\/",
        "BOID": "1205150002440950",
        "FREEBALANCE": 5020,
        "INSTRUMENTNAME": "Business Object Solutions",
        "DRCRFLAG": "CREDIT"
    }
]
jsonDataFromServer = jsonDataFromServer[0];
var keys = Object.keys(jsonDataFromServer),
    data = [];
$.each(keys, function(i, val){
    data.push(new Array(val, jsonDataFromServer[val]));
});
$('#myTable').dataTable({
    "data": data,
    "columns": [
        { "title": "Name" },
        { "title": "Value" }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

hello just follow this example

https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/select_rows.html